# "Failed to perform operation:<describe...> You are not authorized to perform this operation" aws read-only account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have asked to be given access to a client AWS account, to look up some network constructs (subnets, route tables, LBs, VPCs, NAT GWs, etc.), and I was given a read-only one, so people don't get concerned about my changing anything, but once I got access, any step I am trying to conduct, to "view" resources in the region the account should have AWS services, fails with:

"Failed to perform operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation", e.g.:

Failed to perform operation: DescribeRouteTables
You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Failed to perform operation: DescribeSubnets
You are not authorized to perform this operation. ...etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: You weren't given full read-only access. You need to go back to the person that setup your account and ask them to give you the appropriate IAM permissions. Without actually being able to see your account's current IAM policy/policies, there is nothing anyone here can really do to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit: needed to enable MFA. Nowhere in the process was that obvious, but the moment I accessed my account, went in security, and enabled MFA, all resources became available.